# Problems changing a looping java clip's volume

Tags: java, javasound

I am using the following code in a loop to play a music in background:

```
public static void LoopSound(File Sound) {
    try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound));
        FloatControl gainControl = 
                  (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
                gainControl.setValue(-Menu.MV/2);
                if(p==false) {
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
       p=true;
    }
```

I am looping it and when I change Menu.MV the clip's volume doesn't change at all, I saw [Java - Changing volume of a looping Clip seamlessly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927070/java-changing-volume-of-a-looping-clip-seamlessly) and implemented like this:

```
if(volume != Menu.MV/2) {
    volume = Menu.MV/2;
    mp = clip.getFramePosition();
    System.out.println(mp+" frames");
    clip.stop();
    
    FloatControl fc = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
    fc.setValue(-Menu.MV/2);
    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    clip.setFramePosition(mp % clip.getFrameLength());}
```

But it didn't stop the clip playing before and just made new clips with volume changed that started from beginning cause `clip.getFramePosition();` always returns 0, so how do I do to change volume without stopping the clip? Or how do I stop it and make it start in the same place it stopped correctly?

Comment: It looks like the `clip` in `LoopSound` is a local variable; where does `clip` in the second snippet come from?

Comment: is in the method LoopSound as so

Comment: So both snippets are in the same method? How do you expect updates of the `Menu.MV` value to work then - is there some kind of callback? Who changes the value ("Menu" seems to indicate some kind of UI)?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).